# Rephrase "Edit answers and questions" privilege

Tags: feature-request, privileges, wording

The current 2k reputation privilege says "Edit questions and answers". [image]

However, the power to edit questions or answers have already been granted way before 2000 reputation is earned -- these edits simply are not applied immediately and instead require a review.

So, I propose a rephrase for the 2k reputation to clarify the difference of the immediate effects of an edit, something like "Apply edits immediately", to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The [actual description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) in the Help Center (Privileges section) should cover that:

[image]

The key sentence is:

> That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts—anyone's posts!

Comment: Indeed, but the short "Edit questions and answers" phrase would still confuse people at first.